# how to print array in a component - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

this is the code of the StoryCreator

```js
import React from 'react'

import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Layout, Row, Col, Form, Input, Button, Divider, message, Icon, AutoComplete } from 'antd'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import ErrorPopover from '../../components/ErrorPopover/ErrorPopover'
import { success } from '../../services/story.services'

import { changeStoryTitle, changeStoryContent , changeStoryBody, changeStoryImage, changeStoryCategoryid, sendStory } from '../../actions/story.actions'
import { fetchCategories } from '../../actions/category.actions'

import '../../vendor/Shadow/Shadow.css'
import '../../vendor/Radius/Radius.css'
import './StoryCreator.css'

const { Content } = Layout
const FormItem = Form.Item
const { TextArea } = Input;
const onload = () => {
  const hide = message.loading('Cargando entrada..');
};

class StoryCreator extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchCategories())
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.id === 'storyTitle') {
      this.props.dispatch(changeStoryTitle(e.target.value))
    }
  }

  handleChangeContent = (e) => {
    if(e.target.id === 'storyContent') {
      this.props.dispatch(changeStoryContent(e.target.value))
    }
  }

  handleChangeBody = (e) => {
    if(e.target.id === 'storyBody') {
      this.props.dispatch(changeStoryBody(e.target.value))
    }
  }

  handleChangeImage = (e) => {
    if(e.target.id === 'storyImage') {
      this.props.dispatch(changeStoryImage(e.target.value))
    }
  }

  handleChangeCategoryid = (e) => {
    if(e.target.id === 'storyCategoryid') {
      this.props.dispatch(changeStoryCategoryid(e.target.value))
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let storyTitleVal = this.props.storyTitle
    let storyContentVal = this.props.storyContent
    let storyBodyVal = this.props.storyBody
    let storyImageVal = this.props.storyImage
    let storyCategoryidVal = this.props.storyCategoryid

    if (!storyTitleVal) {
      this.storyTitleInput.focus()
      return
    }

    this.props.dispatch(sendStory(storyTitleVal, storyContentVal, storyBodyVal, storyImageVal, storyCategoryidVal), onload)
  }

  render () {

    const {categories} = this.props;
    const data = categories;

    function Complete() {
      return (
        <FormItem style={{marginTop: '-10px'}} label='CATEGORY'>
        <AutoComplete
          style={{ width: 200 }}
          dataSource={data}
          placeholder="try to type `b`"
          filterOption={(inputValue, option) => option.props.children.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1}
        />
        </FormItem>

      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormItem label='TITLE'>
            <Input id='storyTitle' value={this.props.storyTitle} onChange={this.handleChange} ref={(input) => { this.storyTitleInput = input }} size='large' />
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem style={{marginTop: '-10px'}} label='CONTENT'>
            <Input id='storyContent' value={this.props.storyContent} onChange={this.handleChangeContent} ref={(input) => { this.storyContentInput = input }} size='large' />
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem style={{marginTop: '-10px'}} label='Body'>
          <TextArea rows={4} id='storyBody' value={this.props.storyBody} onChange={this.handleChangeBody} ref={(input) => { this.storyBodyInput = input }} size='large'  />
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem style={{marginTop: '-10px'}} label='IMAGE'>
            <Input id='storyImage' value={this.props.storyImage} onChange={this.handleChangeImage} ref={(input) => { this.storyImageInput = input }} size='large' />
          </FormItem>

          <FormItem style={{marginTop: '-10px'}} label='CATEGORY'>
            <Input id='storyCategoryid' value={this.props.storyCategoryid} onChange={this.handleChangeCategoryid} ref={(input) => { this.storyCategoryidInput = input }} size='large' />
          </FormItem>

          <Complete />

          <Button onClick={onload} disabled={this.props.isBusy} style={{marginTop: '-10px'}} type='primary' size='large' htmlType='submit' className='shadow-1'>
            Send
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  const { isBusy } = state.appReducer
  const { storyTitle, storyContent, storyBody, storyImage, storyCategoryid } = state.storyReducer

  return {
    isBusy,
    storyTitle,
    storyContent,
    storyBody,
    storyImage,
    storyCategoryid,
    categories
  }
}

const StoryCreatorConnected = connect(mapStateToProps)(StoryCreator)
export default StoryCreatorConnected
```

and this one of the category.actions

```js
import { CATEGORY_CHANGE_NAME, CATEGORIES_FETCHED, CATEGORY_DELETED } from "../constants/category.constants";
import { showLoading, hideLoading } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'
import { toggleBusy } from '../actions/app.actions'
import { SaveCategory, GetCategories, DeleteCategory, UpdateCategory } from '../services/category.services'
import { history } from '../helpers/history'

export const deleteCategory = (id) => {
    return { type: CATEGORY_DELETED, id: id}
}

export const changeNameCategory = (name) => {
    return { type: CATEGORY_CHANGE_NAME, name: name}
}

export const sendCategory = (name) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(toggleBusy(true))
        dispatch(showLoading())
        SaveCategory(name)
        .then(
            response => {
                dispatch(toggleBusy(false))
                dispatch(hideLoading())
                dispatch(changeNameCategory(''))
                dispatch(fetchCategories())
            },
            error => {
                dispatch(toggleBusy(false))
                dispatch(hideLoading())
            }
        )
    }
}

export const updateCategory = (id, name) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(toggleBusy(true))
        dispatch(showLoading())
        dispatch(changeNameCategory(''))
        history.push('/admin/category')
        UpdateCategory(id, name)
        .then(
            response => {
                dispatch(toggleBusy(false))
                dispatch(hideLoading())
                dispatch(changeNameCategory(''))
                dispatch(fetchCategories())
            },
            error => {
                dispatch(toggleBusy(false))
                dispatch(hideLoading())
            }
        )
    }

}

export const destroyCategory = (id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(toggleBusy(true))
        dispatch(showLoading())
        DeleteCategory(id)
        .then(
            response => {
                dispatch(toggleBusy(false))
                dispatch(hideLoading())
                dispatch(fetchCategories())
            },
            error => {
                dispatch(toggleBusy(false))
                dispatch(hideLoading())
            }
        )
    }
}


export const fetchCategories = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(toggleBusy(true))
        dispatch(showLoading())
        GetCategories()
        .then(
            response => {
                console.log(response)
                dispatch(toggleBusy(false))
                dispatch(hideLoading())
                dispatch(success(response.categories))
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error)
                dispatch(toggleBusy(false))
                dispatch(hideLoading())
            }
        )
    }

    function success(categories) { return { type: CATEGORIES_FETCHED, categories: categories}}
}
```

what it does is communicate with a service to be able to take all the loaded categories, the problem is that I can not put all those categories in a variable to be able to list them in an Autocomplete, I do not know how to load the array into a variable.

The strange thing is that I could do it before in another component that lists all the categories. There I leave the code, I hope you can help me

```js
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {
  Card,
  Alert,
  Icon,
  Button,
  Table,
  Divider,
  Popconfirm
} from 'antd';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {fetchCategories, destroyCategory, editCategory} from '../../actions/category.actions';
const {Meta} = Card;


class Categories extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchCategories())
  }
  handleDeleteCategory(e) {
    //var removedItem = fruits.splice(pos, 1);
    this.props.dispatch(destroyCategory(e.id))
  }


  render() {
    const {categories} = this.props;
    const data = categories;

    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        key: 'id'
      }, {
        title: 'Nombre de la categoria',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name'
      }, {
        title: 'Acciones',
        key: 'action',
        render: (text, record) => (<span>
           <Link to={`/admin/category/edit/${record.id}/${record.name}`}>Editar</Link>
          <span className="ant-divider"/>
          <a onClick={() => this.handleDeleteCategory(record)}>Eliminar</a>
        </span>)
      }
    ];

    if (this.props.categories.length == 0)
      return (<Alert message="No hay categorias para mostrar." type="error"/>);

    return <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns}/>

  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {categories} = state.categoryReducer
  return {categories}
}

const connectedCategories = connect(mapStateToProps)(Categories)
export default connectedCategories
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it, forget to import the variable to the mapStateToProps and to reduce. Thank you!